# Need help optimizing SQL query in Opencart with Journal theme

Tags: sql, database, indexing, query-optimization, opencart

I'm working on a project using Opencart with the Journal theme, and I've encountered a performance issue with a complex SQL query. This query is responsible for fetching product data, including ratings, discounts, specials, and sales quantities. However, it seems to be slow, and I'm looking for ways to optimize it. I have loads of up to 55 sec caused by it. Its consuming and reaching my CPU limits.

Here's the SQL query I'm currently using:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    (
        SELECT AVG(rating) total
        FROM `oc_review` r1
        WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id
        AND r1.status = '1'
        GROUP BY r1.product_id
    ) rating,
    (
        SELECT price
        FROM `oc_product_discount` pd2
        WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id
        AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1'
        AND pd2.quantity = '1'
        AND (
            (pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW())
            AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())
        )
        ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) discount,
    (
        SELECT price
        FROM `oc_product_special` ps
        WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id
        AND ps.customer_group_id = '1'
        AND (
            (ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW())
            AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())
        )
        ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) special,
    p.viewed,
    SUM(op.quantity) AS sales
FROM `oc_order_product` op
LEFT JOIN `oc_order` o ON (o.order_id = op.order_id)
LEFT JOIN `oc_product` p ON (p.product_id = op.product_id)
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
LEFT JOIN `oc_product_to_store` p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
WHERE p.status = '1'
AND p.date_available <= NOW()
AND p2s.store_id = '0'
AND pd.language_id = '2'
AND o.order_status_id > '0'
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY sales DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

I suspect that this query could be optimized to improve performance. Any suggestions or insights into how I can make it more efficient would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you guys

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've reviewed the SQL query for correctness and ensured that it's functioning as intended.
I've verified that the necessary indexes are in place for the involved tables.
I've checked the server environment for any potential resource bottlenecks.

However, I'm facing a performance issue where this query seems to execute slowly. I believe there might be room for optimization, but due to my limited database expertise, I'm struggling to pinpoint the exact areas that need improvement.

What I'm expecting:

I'm seeking guidance and expertise from the Stack Overflow community to help me understand:

If there are any obvious performance bottlenecks or inefficiencies in the provided query.
Potential optimizations or alternative approaches to achieve the same result more efficiently.
Any insights or suggestions on how to interpret the query execution plan or profile it for better performance.

Comment: This query will not run on SQL Server. This syntax isn't T-SQL, it looks like MySql. I've Removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query (and tag your question with the relevant DBMS)

Comment: Hi - so where’s the output of the EXPLAIN PLAN? Also, you still haven’t tagged your question with the DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) that you are using

Comment: Refactor your query to replace your [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) with independent subqueries. That will make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of small problems and a few big ones in that query.  I’ll run down a list of what stands out to me here - some of which may involve significant changes to the application core since it has some design problems (I’ve been working with Opencart since 2012).

1. All of the subqueries with conditions like this `pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()` are unable to use an index (if there even is one in your version) due to the presence of that `OR`.  In the admin panel when you leave those fields blank they are written as `0000-00-00` which necessitates checking both - not to mention this is an illegal datetime value so best not to use it.  A better approach is to set `date_start` to `0000-01-01` when left blank and `date_end` to `9999-01-01` and then change the query from:

```
AND (
    (pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW())
    AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())
)
```

To

```
AND pd2.date_start < NOW()
AND pd2.date_end > NOW()
```

Voilà, now you can add a full index on the search fields.  Even if you don't the DBMS will be able to optimize significantly. The challenge here obviously is that you will need to rewrite some of that admin logic.  I've done this on a site in the past and the performance gain was substantial.

2. All of those `LEFT JOINS` are nonsense.  The `WHERE` conditions at the bottom require them so they should be `RIGHT` or `INNER` joins (same thing in MySQL). You can rewrite this:

```
LEFT JOIN `oc_order` o ON (o.order_id = op.order_id)
...
WHERE
...
AND o.order_status_id > '0'
```

Like this (`JOIN` without a specifier defaults to `INNER JOIN` so you can leave the keyword out for easier reading):

```
JOIN `oc_order` o ON o.order_id = op.order_id AND o.order_status_id > 0
```

Same goes for the rest of them. I hope that makes sense - the point is, if the table is required, *put your condition in the `JOIN`*.

3. Depending on the size of your dataset, it's going to be tricky grouping and sorting by aggregate values like the sum of your sales and expecting things to go well.  I suspect this query is used for a "Bestsellers" view or something of the sort. In that case, it would be better to either create a special search table or add a column to your product table with a value that gets updated daily.  You don't need a bleeding edge number for total sales - just something to put your bestsellers at the top.  Of course - you'll need to update that column regularly with cron or when an order is placed.
4. `pd.name` is probably not case sensitive.  Lose the `LCASE()` function to gain some performance and possibly use of an index.

That would be a start anyway. Cheers.